# how to get tax percentage based on zipcode

Tags: php, e-commerce

i am building a custom ecommerce system. how do i get the most current tax rates based on the zipcode? i was thinking of just creating a table and listing all the state tax rates but the thing is the info changes yearly and it might be hard to track and update. 
would their be any apis that i can use? btw im using php

the one thing i need to be clear in us when a product is purchased, is the taxes applied only for shipping? or it needs to be applied for the item as well?

so would the total be calculated like this?

product: $100

shipping(ground) $4.75

tax(ca): 5%

total: 104.99

Comment: This is...not really programming related.

Comment: You should probably seek qualified legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little more complicated than just a zip code to a tax rate.  Take a look at [zip 2 tax](http://www.zip2tax.com/).  The tax rate is also effected by what you are selling.  Some places do not place a sales tax on food.  Some places tax "hot" food but not food that you take home to cook.  So a grocery store will charge a tax rate for noodles that is different than a pre-cooked chicken from the Deli.  Some places have a tax on junk food - any food that is more than X % sugar.  It can vary by county.  It can vary by location where some people are in a city and other are not in the city in the same county.

Comment: yea when it comes to taxes its best to know all the details , it can get tricky. thnx for that ill look around at what other carts are doing

Answer (score 0):

Try this service

http://dor.wa.gov/Content/FindTaxesAndRates/RetailSalesTax/DestinationBased/ClientInterface.aspx

Comment: Looks like a good service but it only works for the state of Washington.